# Showing a scheme is convergent through Von Neumann stability analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, stability-in-odes

> Show that the box scheme
>
> $$\frac{1}{2k}\Big[(U_j^{n+1}+U_{j+1}^{n+1})-(U_j^n + U_{j+1}^n)\Big]+\frac{a}{2h}\Big[(U_{j+1}^{n+1}-U_{j}^{n+1})+(U_{j+1}^n - U_{j}^n)\Big]$$
>
> is convergent for the one-way wave equation
>
> $$u_t+au_x=0, ~~~-\infty<x<\infty, ~t>0,~ x\in\mathbb R$$

Using von Neumann stability analysis and letting

$$U_j^n=g(\xi)^ne^{ijh\xi}$$

where

$$h\xi=\theta$$

one finds that

$$(g+g e^{i\theta})-(1+e^{i\theta})+\frac{ak}{h}((g e^{i\theta}-g)+(e^{i\theta}-1)=0$$

which reduces to

$$g=\frac{(1+e^{i\theta})-\frac{ak}{h}(e^{i\theta}-1)}{(1+e^{i\theta})+\frac{ak}{h}(e^{i\theta}-1)}$$

The goal is to show that

$$|g|\leq 1$$

or

$$\Bigg|\frac{(1+e^{i\theta})-\frac{ak}{h}(e^{i\theta}-1)}{(1+e^{i\theta})+\frac{ak}{h}(e^{i\theta}-1)}\Bigg|\leq 1$$

However, I cannot seen to get this argument to work. If I try

$$g=\frac{(1+e^{i\theta})-z}{(1+e^{i\theta})+z}$$

where

$$z=\frac{ak}{h}(e^{i\theta}-1)$$

then I see that

$$z\leq 0 ~~\Rightarrow ~~ |g|\leq 1$$

However, this doesn't make any sense as $z$ is defined as a complex number. Is there a different approach of attack for the final step of this problem?

I think that the scheme is stable for all choices of $a,k,$ and $h$ (and therefore convergent by the Lax Equivalence Theorem). However, I cannot find a way of reducing the final inequality to find the valid range of values for

$$\frac{ak}{h}$$